# How to fetch unique item from redux with conditional operator?

Tags: reactjs, redux, web-deployment

I am trying to fetch only unique data from the redux store but got all values from the redux store.
I use usePerma hook to check id from URL and id of redux data then apply ternary operator but did not get desired output. See the output image and code and please tell how to get only one value from that.

When URL is 1002 only 1002 is item should show but its also showing 1001 item.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useStateValue } from './Stateprovider';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

const User = () => {
    const [{basket}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

    const {id} = useParams();

    return (
        <>
             {basket.map((item) => (
                <>
                {
                    ({id} === {item.id}) ?   //Error
                    <div key="id" className="card">
                    <img src={item.Image} alt="" />
                    <div className="card-data">
                    <h3><span>User Id: </span>{item.id}</h3>
                    <h2><span>Name: </span>{item.name}</h2>
                    </div>
                     <NavLink className="button" exact to='/home' > User Info </NavLink>
                </div>
                 : null
                }
                </>
             ))}
        </>
    )
}

export default User;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to map *only* the items from the `basket` array that match the `id` match param. For this you can either use `Array.prototype.find` to first find the matching item and conditionally render if found, or use `Array.prototype.filter` and just filter the array inline.

Filtering the array inline:

```
const User = () => {
  const [{basket}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      {basket
        .filter(item => item.id === id)
        .map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id} className="card">
            <img src={item.Image} alt="" />
            <div className="card-data">
              <h3><span>User Id: </span>{item.id}</h3>
              <h2><span>Name: </span>{item.name}</h2>
            </div>
            <NavLink className="button" exact to='/home'>
              User Info
            </NavLink>
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

Finding first, then rendering: *remember that `.find` returns undefined if no match is found*

```
const User = () => {
  const [{basket}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  const { id } = useParams();

  const item = basket.find(item => item.id === id);

  return item ? (
    <div className="card">
      <img src={item.Image} alt="" />
      <div className="card-data">
        <h3><span>User Id: </span>{item.id}</h3>
        <h2><span>Name: </span>{item.name}</h2>
      </div>
      <NavLink className="button" exact to='/home'>
        User Info
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  ) : null;
}
```

Comment: @AnkitKumar Is this related to this question and issue, or is it a new and separate question? You could just search the redux state if the value is already there and update (*if necessary*) if it is, or add new if it isn't.